# Grouping by each hour for each weekday

Tags: sql, database, postgresql, join

I have a table `orders`

```
  id  |  price  |  items_count  |         created_at
------+---------+---------------+------------------------
   1  |  16.50  |      3        | 2015-07-21 12:52:00.824
   2  |  50.00  |      1        | 2015-07-21 12:54:42.658
   3  |  12.00  |     10        | 2015-07-22 07:21:47.808
   .  |   .     |      .        |             .
   .  |   .     |      .        |             .
   .  |   .     |      .        |             .
```

and so on...

Now I want to get *number of orders* and *sum of their prices* from last month grouped by *weekdays* (as numbers from 0 to 6) and *hours* (as numbers from 0 to 23).

What I managed to do is:

```
SELECT EXTRACT('dow' FROM to_timezone(created_at, 'CEST', 0)) AS DAY,
(EXTRACT('hour' FROM to_timezone(created_at, 'CEST', 0)) + 0)::INT % 24 AS HOUR,
COUNT(DISTINCT id) AS orders_count,
SUM(price) AS price_total
FROM orders
WHERE created_at BETWEEN '2015-06-30 22:00:00.000000'
AND '2015-07-31 21:59:59.999999'
GROUP BY extract('dow' from to_timezone(created_at, 'CEST', 0)),
EXTRACT('hour' from to_timezone(created_at, 'CEST', 0))
ORDER BY 1 ASC, EXTRACT('hour' from to_timezone(created_at, 'CEST', 0));
```

And here is what I get -  **current result**:

```
 day | hour | orders_count | price_total
-----+------+--------------+-------------
   0 |    7 |           11 |    298.00
   0 |    9 |            8 |     64.00
   1 |    8 |            1 |     12.50
   1 |   12 |            3 |     69.00 
   2 |   10 |            2 |    112.00
   2 |   13 |            1 |    100.00
   2 |   14 |           13 |   2163.70
   2 |   21 |            4 |    357.00
```

and so on...

Now I want to include **all hours** in a day and put `0` in `orders_count` and `price_total` columns if there were no orders in given hour. So my **desired result** should look like this:

```
 day | hour | orders_count | price_total
-----+------+--------------+-------------
   0 |    0 |            0 |      0.00
   0 |    1 |            0 |      0.00
   0 |    2 |            0 |      0.00
   0 |    3 |            0 |      0.00
   0 |    4 |            0 |      0.00
   0 |    5 |            0 |      0.00
   0 |    6 |            0 |      0.00
   0 |    7 |           11 |    298.00
   0 |    8 |            0 |      0.00
   0 |    9 |            8 |     64.00
   0 |   10 |            0 |      0.00
```

and so on - I need 7 days `[0,6]` and for each day 24 hours `[0,23]` with `0` in aggregate columns.

---

I came up with an idea to use `generate_series` to get **all hours** in a day:

```
SELECT EXTRACT(hour from generate_series)
FROM generate_series('2015-07-01 00:00'::timestamp, '2015-07-01 23:00', '1 hour');
```

My problem is that I don't know how to combine my **current result** with **all hours**. What kind of `JOIN` should I use? And how to insert `0`s in previously mentioned columns when there are no orders for a given row?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Form a [Cartesian product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cartesian_product) of days and hours with a `CROSS JOIN`.
2. `LEFT JOIN` to the aggregated sums per `(day, hour)` - conveniently with the `USING` clause to fold columns into one instance.

[Joins in the manual.](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/queries-table-expressions.html#QUERIES-FROM)

```
SELECT day, hour
     , COALESCE(orders_count, 0)  AS orders_count
     , COALESCE(price_total, 0.0) AS price_total
FROM         generate_series(0,6)  day
CROSS  JOIN  generate_series(0,23) hour
LEFT   JOIN (
   SELECT EXTRACT('dow'  FROM created_at AT TIME ZONE 'CEST')::int AS day
        , EXTRACT('hour' FROM created_at AT TIME ZONE 'CEST')::int AS hour
        , count(DISTINCT id) AS orders_count
        , sum(price)         AS price_total
   FROM   orders
   WHERE  created_at BETWEEN '2015-06-30 22:00:00.000000'
                         AND '2015-07-31 21:59:59.999999'
   GROUP  BY 1, 2
   ) o USING (day, hour)
ORDER  BY 1, 2;
```

Also cleaned up your query a bit.
Using the standard SQL construct `AT TIME ZONE` instead of the Postgres function `to_timezone()`. Details:

- [Ignoring timezones altogether in Rails and PostgreSQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9571392/ignoring-timezones-altogether-in-rails-and-postgresql/9576170#9576170)

Removed the redundant modulo operator <strike>`% 24`</strike>.

Use [`COALESCE()`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/functions-conditional.html#FUNCTIONS-COALESCE-NVL-IFNULL) to replace `NULL` with `0` or `0.0`.